# IndexError: string index out of range python, numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Have a long [code](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5832541) that I've been tearing my hair out over. If I run an input file

```
# 96.52 0.0036
#
#
0.860    9.38   0.938   35   I      I_band
1.235    6.452   0.030  41   J      2MASS 
1.66     5.471   0.021  42   H      2MASS 
2.16     5.069   0.023  43   K      2MASS 
9.0          9.760e-01   8.51e-03   0    AKARI09     0.52
18.0     2.609e-01   3.67e-02   0    AKARI18     0.52
#
```

I get

```
File 'myfile.py', line 811, in <module>
err=np.append(err,data[i][2])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

However, if I run

```
# 96.52 0.0036
#
#
0.860    9.38   0.938   35   I      I_band
1.235    6.452   0.030  41   J      2MASS 0.134
1.66     5.471   0.021  42   H      2MASS 0.134
2.16     5.069   0.023  43   K      2MASS 0.134
9.0          9.760e-01   8.51e-03   0    AKARI09     0.52
18.0     2.609e-01   3.67e-02   0    AKARI18     0.52
#
```

The code works as it should. Both those examples are saved as a .dat file that I am prompted to direct the code towards.

I've been trying to figure this out for maybe 24 hours now (I know, right?) with absolutely no success. I can't pinpoint my problem. ANY advice would be welcomed at this point. Thanks as always!

EDIT: if I change (around the 800 line) the xranges to 'range' and extend back to append (see lines 792 and 798) I will now get this error:

```
File 'myfile.py', line 807, in <module>
 if(data[i]=='#'): comments=comments+1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to follow through the 1000+ lines of your code (and I doubt many will). But from what I could glance, you seem to be trying to reinvent the wheel in the way you read your files. You are getting the error because your `data` array in some columns does not have the type/size you expect.

I'd suggest getting acquainted with numpy's [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) functions. You can probably get most of the file's data in the format that you want with a single call. (All the open calls in your code seem to be in binary, so I don't know how the text file enters.) I don't know exactly what your format is, but for example you do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.genfromtxt('file', dtype=[('wave','f'), ('flux', 'f'),
                                      ('err', 'f'), ('code', 'i'), 
                                      ('band', 'S8'), ('survey', 'S8')])
```

The result is a structured array which you can index by the `dtype` strings:

```
In [16]: result['wave']
Out[16]:
array([  0.86000001,   1.23500001,   1.65999997,   2.16000009,
         9.        ,  18.        ], dtype=float32)

In [17]: result['err']
Out[17]:
array([ 0.93800002,  0.03      ,  0.021     ,  0.023     ,  0.00851   ,
        0.0367    ], dtype=float32)

In [18]: result['band']
Out[18]:
array(['I', 'J', 'H', 'K', 'AKARI09', 'AKARI18'],
      dtype='|S8')
```

Here I saved the last column as string, so you may have to convert the numbers in the last two rows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is someone else's code and I'm trying to get it to work for multiple data files. Frustrating. Thanks again.